# Atom editor: Emmet not working in php file

Tags: php, atom-editor, emmet

I'm coding my new wordpress theme by Atom editor. But emmet tab expand not working in php file but working fine in html file. How can i make emmet tab expand working in php file?

Many thank,

Comment: I got same problem - [refer here](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/108)

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really new, but I just had the same problem.

The package [emmet-snippets-compatibility](https://atom.io/packages/emmet-snippets-compatibility) can be installed via Atom's package manager and will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had found myself solution.
In your **keymap.cson** (*File -> Settings -> Keybindings -> Click to your keymap file*) please add following: 

`'.pane .editor:not(.mini)':
  'ctrl-shift-tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation'`

*Source: [https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/134](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom/issues/134_)*

Comment: More of a workaround than a solution, anyone have an idea of how to let emmet use html expansions within .php files naturally?